# get location area code and cell id from CellInfoLte

Tags: android

After calling `getAllCellInfo()` method on `TelephonyManager`, I get a list of `CellInfo`.
The question is: if instanceof `CellInfo` is `CellInfoLte`, how can I get cell id and lac code from it?

I have tried `getCi()`. but the value seems too big

```
            CellInfoLte infoLte = (CellInfoLte) info;
            CellIdentityLte cellIdentity = infoLte.getCellIdentity();
            CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrength = infoLte.getCellSignalStrength();
            cid = cellIdentity.getCi();
            lac = cellIdentity.getTac();
            ss = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
```

PS: also I want to get cid from `CellInfoCdma`.

Comment: Instead of cid in CDMA use `CellIdentityCdma.getBasestationId()`, geolocation api's accept that. And I believe that `CellIdentityLte.getTac()` is the same as lac (tracking area code maybe the same as location area code)

Answer (score 0):

Cid and Lac code from CellInfoCdma not possible.(Actually CDMA does not provide these only GSM provide this)